# How to implement decorator in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am learning Rust and I am stuck with a toy example. I have already read documentation on lifetimes, this [post](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) and a bunch of questions on Stack Overflow. I've spent more than a week, but I'm still stuck, so I decided to ask for help from a community.

I have a generic trait `BookSide` which returns `BookIterator` (which extends usual `Iterator`). And I have two implementations for both `BookSide` and `BookIterator`: `ArrayBookSide` and `CommissionBookSide`.

1. First one is stateful. It has a `Vec` under the hood.
2. Second one is stateless: it wraps some other `BookSide`.

My goal is simply to compile the whole thing. I was solving problems and followed the suggestions of the compiler. This process resulted in the following code.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

// traits

pub trait BookIterator<'a>: Iterator<Item=f64> {}

pub trait BookSide<'a> {
    type BookIteratorType: BookIterator<'a>;

    fn book_iterator(&self) -> Self::BookIteratorType;
}

// implementation 1: stateful

pub struct ArrayBookSide {
    quotes: Vec<f64>,
}

pub struct ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {
    quotes_iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, f64>,
}

impl<'a> BookSide<'a> for ArrayBookSide {
    type BookIteratorType = ArrayBookSideIterator<'a>;

    fn book_iterator(&self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
        ArrayBookSideIterator { quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter() }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.quotes_iter.next().map(|&quote| quote)
    }
}

impl<'a> BookIterator<'a> for ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {}

// implementation 2: delegating

pub struct CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
    where B: BookSide<'a> {
    base_book_side: B,
    multiplier: f64,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a B>,
}

impl<'a, B> CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
    where B: BookSide<'a> {
    pub fn new(base_book_side: B) -> CommissionBookSide<'a, B> {
        CommissionBookSide { base_book_side, multiplier: 1.1, _marker: PhantomData {} }
    }
}

impl<'a, B> BookSide<'a> for CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
    where B: BookSide<'a> {
    type BookIteratorType = CommissionIterator<'a, B::BookIteratorType>;

    fn book_iterator(&self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
        CommissionIterator {
            base_iterator: self.base_book_side.book_iterator(),
            multiplier: self.multiplier,
            _marker: PhantomData {},
        }
    }
}

pub struct CommissionIterator<'a, BI>
    where BI: BookIterator<'a> {
    base_iterator: BI,
    multiplier: f64,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a BI>,
}

impl<'a, BI> Iterator for CommissionIterator<'a, BI>
    where BI: BookIterator<'a> {
    type Item = BI::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.base_iterator.next().map(|quote| quote * self.multiplier)
    }
}

impl<'a, BI> BookIterator<'a> for CommissionIterator<'a, BI>
    where BI: BookIterator<'a> {}
```

Now I have the following compile error.

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:31:58
   |
31 |         ArrayBookSideIterator { quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter() }
   |                                                          ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 30:5...
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 | /     fn book_iterator(&self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
31 | |         ArrayBookSideIterator { quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter() }
32 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:31:46
   |
31 |         ArrayBookSideIterator { quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter() }
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 27:6...
  --> src/main.rs:27:6
   |
27 | impl<'a> BookSide<'a> for ArrayBookSide {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:30:55
   |
30 |       fn book_iterator(&self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
   |  _______________________________________________________^
31 | |         ArrayBookSideIterator { quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter() }
32 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `BookSide<'a>`
              found `BookSide<'_>`
```

I probably shouldn't use `PhantomData`? It looks like an over complication and a workaround to me. I have published the [full code here](https://github.com/vad0/books/blob/master/src/main.rs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue essentially boils down to the following. What's the issue here?

```rust
fn book_iterator<'a>(slice: &[f64]) -> std::slice::Iter<'a, f64> {
    //                      ^^^^^^ needs to be `&'a [f64]`
    slice.iter()
}
```

The method `book_iterator(&self)` returns a `BookIterator<'a>`. Where does the `'a` come from? It comes from `&self` of course, so annotate it as `&'a self` and the code compiles:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

// traits

pub trait BookIterator<'a>: Iterator<Item = f64> {}

pub trait BookSide<'a> {
    type BookIteratorType: BookIterator<'a>;

    // 'a added here in trait method signature
    fn book_iterator(&'a self) -> Self::BookIteratorType;
}

// implementation 1: stateful

pub struct ArrayBookSide {
    quotes: Vec<f64>,
}

pub struct ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {
    quotes_iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, f64>,
}

impl<'a> BookSide<'a> for ArrayBookSide {
    type BookIteratorType = ArrayBookSideIterator<'a>;

    // 'a added here below
    fn book_iterator(&'a self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
        ArrayBookSideIterator {
            quotes_iter: self.quotes.iter(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {
    type Item = f64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.quotes_iter.next().map(|&quote| quote)
    }
}

impl<'a> BookIterator<'a> for ArrayBookSideIterator<'a> {}

// implementation 2: delegating

pub struct CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
where
    B: BookSide<'a>,
{
    base_book_side: B,
    multiplier: f64,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a B>,
}

impl<'a, B> CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
where
    B: BookSide<'a>,
{
    pub fn new(base_book_side: B) -> CommissionBookSide<'a, B> {
        CommissionBookSide {
            base_book_side,
            multiplier: 1.1,
            _marker: PhantomData {},
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, B> BookSide<'a> for CommissionBookSide<'a, B>
where
    B: BookSide<'a>,
{
    type BookIteratorType = CommissionIterator<'a, B::BookIteratorType>;

    // 'a added here before
    fn book_iterator(&'a self) -> Self::BookIteratorType {
        CommissionIterator {
            base_iterator: self.base_book_side.book_iterator(),
            multiplier: self.multiplier,
            _marker: PhantomData {},
        }
    }
}

pub struct CommissionIterator<'a, BI>
where
    BI: BookIterator<'a>,
{
    base_iterator: BI,
    multiplier: f64,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a BI>,
}

impl<'a, BI> Iterator for CommissionIterator<'a, BI>
where
    BI: BookIterator<'a>,
{
    type Item = BI::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.base_iterator
            .next()
            .map(|quote| quote * self.multiplier)
    }
}

impl<'a, BI> BookIterator<'a> for CommissionIterator<'a, BI> where BI: BookIterator<'a> {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=623d327f8f4f507224c5bd1673057884)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that it works it looks so simple!

Comment: I still have a question. Why is it necessary to annotate `self`? It is already annotated with the same lifetime name in declaration, isn't it? Looks like a duplication.

Comment: The declaration `BookIterator<'a>` says that `BookIterator` is generic over lifetimes, but there's still no indication where those lifetimes may come from, they may come from `&self` or they may come from somewhere else entirely, that's why you still need to explicitly annotate `&self` as `&'a self` because in this particular case they are coming from `&self`.